# Date formatting and assignment

Tags: java, date, date-formatting

I have date in string format of (yyyy-MM-dd), i want to assign this with same format to Date object.

i tried with new SimpleDateFormat(yyy-MM-dd).parse(dateString) and further assigned it to Date, but format not carry.

`new SimpleDateFormat(yyy-MM-dd).parse(dateString);`

No error in parsing

Comment: Date objects do not include formatting information. Also, it's probably about time to start using the `java.time` classes instead of the legacy `java.util` stuff.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). BTW `LccalDate` does print in the format you asked for since it is what its `toString` method produces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
```

In your case three letter `y` but four needed

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contriute. I’m afraid that it won’t make any difference.

Comment: Yes it will not impact since assignment is in Date object so format will wiped out. Anyway thanks for contribute.